# Why does this generator skip a yield outside the try block?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, generator

**Background**

I am experimenting with how `Generator.prototype.throw()` works and made this example:

```
var myGen = function *() {

    try{
        yield 1;
        yield 2;
        yield 3;
        yield 4;
        yield 5;
    }

    catch(err) {

        console.log(err);
    }

    yield 7;
    yield 8;
    yield 9;

}

var myIterator = myGen();

console.log(myIterator.next());
console.log(myIterator.next());
console.log(myIterator.next());

myIterator.throw(new Error('Bullocks!'));

console.log(myIterator.next());
console.log(myIterator.next());
console.log(myIterator.next());
```

which at runtime results in the following:

```
{ value: 1, done: false }
{ value: 2, done: false }
{ value: 3, done: false }
[Error: Bullocks!]
{ value: 8, done: false }
{ value: 9, done: false }
{ value: undefined, done: true }
```

**Question**

I can understand that `yield 4` and the remaining part of the `try` block is skipped after throwing an error.

But why does the generator skip `yield 7`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It doesn't skip `yield 7`.  When you call `throw()`, the control flow goes into the `catch` block, the error is logged, and then the execution continues until the next `yield` upon which a new iterator result object `{ value: 7, done: false }` is returned.

It's just that in your code you don't `console.log` this one particular result object.  Try:

```
console.log(myIterator.throw(new Error('Bullocks!')));
```

This is explained in [step 11 and 13 of the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-generatorresumeabrupt):

> 11. Resume the suspended evaluation of genContext using abruptCompletion as the result of the operation that suspended it. Let result be the completion record returned by the resumed computation.
> 12. (…)
> 13. Return Completion(result).

Comment: Thank you. So the `.throw()` statement actually works just like the `.next()` statement in terms of causing the generator to yield out the value of the next `yield` statement .... ?

Comment: Precisely. It resumes the generator with an added special effect of throwing an error inside of it.  The action of resuming is the same as with `next()`: it resumes until the next `yield` and returns a new iterator result objet `{value, done}`.

Comment: Thanks. Being an employee at Mozilla: Maybe there is a little room for improvement in the explanation for `Generator.prototype.throw()` in the Mozilla - otherwise excellent - documentation .... :) It does not state anything about returning an object. I actually thought the `.throw` statement was just about "throwing" ....

Comment: Good suggestion. I edited the MDN docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator/throw$compare?locale=en-US&to=1047198&from=980855.  Feel free to update them yourself in the future; it's a wiki! :)

Comment: Ok - wasn't aware of that :) Thanks for doing it.